# Proposition of an optimized rendering technical with batches using OpenGL and GLSL

Tags: opengl, optimization, 3d, shader

I am looking for a sort method to optimize the rendering of a scene (regardless the number of meshes and their sizes) minimizing the states changes and maximizing the geometry gathering to have the fewest call of `glDraw*` functions.

In my proposal, the most judicious choice to render a specific batch is the function `glMultiDrawElements` because it takes an array of indices (one for each model contained in the batch) to render a batch. Plus, it should be perfect for the space partitioning (if a mesh is not visible in the frustum of the camera, a boolean flag `m_IsVisible` will be turned to false. In this case, the indices of this specific geometry will not be included and thus will not be rendered).

So, here is my proposition I want to share with someone interested by the subject. For a sake of lisibility I took a few time to show you my demonstration properly on a WORD project):

Here's the criteria I need to sort my geometry during the initialization (there are ordered by pertinence). They could be gathered in an enum:

```
enum E__SortingCriteria
{
    GEOMETRY_CRITERION (geometry storage -> VBOs)
    SHADER_PROGRAM_CRITERION
    MATERIAL_CRITERION
    TEXTURE_CRITERION
};
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

As you can see, the state changes and the geometry gathering seems to be optimized. However, I am concerned that something may not be correct or that there is room for improvement.